# Converting an integer in String form to char octets

Tags: java, encoding, ascii

I need some help with a Java program.

I am trying to take a String containing an integer and convert it to a more compact storage format, namely, a couple of octet chars that will be printed into a file. When the file is read, it should be able to take the chars and combine their values to get the original int back. Is there a way to do this? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have a String that really contains an int like "12345" and you want to write it compactly in a file.

First, you convert the string to an int:

```
int value = Integer.valueOf(string);
```

Then you either convert it to a byte array with a ByteBuffer:

```
ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
b.putInt(value);
byte[] result = b.array();
```

Or you simply write it in a file:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
oos.writeInt(value);
```

**Edit**: Since you still have difficulties, here is a complete example:

```
public class Snippet {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = Integer.parseInt("1234567890");

    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(4);
    b.putInt(value);
    byte[] result = b.array();

    System.out.println(result.length);  // 4
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result)); // [73, -106, 2, -46]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but it only wrote a single character for "1234567890"

Comment: I have updated my answer with a complete example. This should work. If you still can't make your code work, try to post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I used the ByteBuffer to print the value into a file, and it seems to work. The file contains the four characters "I–Ò" (there is a non-printing character in between the '-' and 'Ò'). Now I need to be able to read it back from the file and get the original string. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Integer.toOctalString(Integer.parseInt([String Value]))`. This will give you a octal string.
To get back the integer, use `Integer.parseInt([Octal string],8);`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Integer.valueOf(yourstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
public static String toHexString(int i)
```

and

```
 public static int parseInt(String s, int radix)
```

with a radix of 16 as a way of "compressing" your string to hexadecimal.

Alternatively you could just use the serialization methods on the integer itself if the file is a binary one.

Answer (score 0):

to convert string to int use

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(String)
```

the most compact way to save `int` to a file is in binary representation

```
java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt(i);
```

read it back as

```
int i = java.io.DataInputStream.readInt();
```

Comment: It seems to be working, but it only prints one character for the string "1234567890".